# Reference type in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

It is possible to make the first type in the dictionary a reference type?
And if yes, what sense of that?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
Dictionary<T1, T2> myDict = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
```

As I understand it, the first type - is the key. And more often than it is of type **int** or **string**.

Comment: Yes, you can use reference type as `TKey`. It actually doesn't matter if it's a struct or a class. I don't really understand why you think it has no sense.

Comment: try it and see whether it's possible or not.

Comment: You know `string` is a class (and thus reference type) as well, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a reference type or not because it uses hashed values, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is fine to use a reference type as the key in your dictionary. The important thing to remember if you do so, is that reference types use reference equality as default.

If you want multiple instances of your key type to represent the same value, then you need to make sure that your reference type uses value equality. For example `string` is a reference type that already supports value equality, so it is safe and easy to use a string as your key.

**The problem:**

The following reference type does not implement value equality:

```
class Foo
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}
```

So, if you create two instances, holding the same value, they are not considered equal:

```
var a = new Foo { X = 1 };
var b = new Foo { X = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(a == b); // false
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); // false
```

If you store a value in a dictionary using `a` as the key, you will not be able to retrieve it using `b`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Foo, int>();
dict[a] = 10;
Console.WriteLine(dict[b]); // Key not found exception
```

**Solutions**

To solve this you can either (I) implement value equality for your type, or (II) override the way your dictionary compares keys:

**Option I:** Implementing value equality:

So if you did want to implement value equality for your reference type you should follow [these guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183755.aspx), and that will give you something like this (don't forget about `GetHashCode`):

```
class Foo2 : IEquatable<Foo2>
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Foo2);
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo2 other)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Optimization for a common success case. 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (this.GetType() != other.GetType())
            return false;

        return (X == other.X);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Foo2 lhs, Foo2 rhs)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo2 lhs, Foo2 rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }
}
```

Now two instances of `Foo2` representing the same value are considered equal:

```
var c = new Foo2 { X = 1 };
var d = new Foo2 { X = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(c == d); // true
Console.WriteLine(c.Equals(d)); // true
```

If you store a value in a dictionary using `c` as the key, you **will** be able to retrieve it using `d`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Foo2, int>();
dict[c] = 10;
Console.WriteLine(dict[d]); // 10
```

**Option II:** Using a custom equality comparer:

If you are not going to typically compare instances of `Foo`, but still want to be able to use value equality when comparing them in a dictionary, you can provide a custom equality comparer as an alternative to implementing full value equality:

```
class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{

    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        // Doesn't handle null arguments!
        return x.X == y.X;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
    {
        return obj.X;
    }
}
```

`a` and `b` are still considered not equal, but now you can store a value in the dictionary using `a`, and retrieve it using `b`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Foo, int>(new FooComparer());
dict[a] = 10;
Console.WriteLine(dict[b]); // 10
```

Comment: +1 for complete sample... Also changing a type just to be able to use as key in dictionary may be overkill, consider implementing `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` and using corresponding [Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Constructor (IEqualityComparer<TKey>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good point. I've added an example of that option too.

Answer (score 3):

Every object in the .NET framework has the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods. And those are all that is required to be used as a key in a dictionary.

A default reference type uses referential equality (i.e. is the key the same object in memory), but you can override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to give whatever equality semantics you like.

Comment: +1. To be precise even implementing `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods on a type is not necessary - [Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows to use any object as a key as long as you provide proper custom comparer.